# Ormlite with JPA annotation

Tags: android, jpa, ormlite, code-reuse

I have a project that the client want me to re-use (by sharing src directory directly) their existing JPA-annotated classes on Android.  I would like to use ormlite in my project (despite the underlying DB will be H2) but the classes use some JPA annotations that ormlite does not support (`@IdClass` with composite primary key object, entity with multiple `@Id` columns, `@OneToMany`).

My question is, Will configuring the classes using Java code override the JPA annotations? Or is there other ways around this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing in a `DatabaseTableConfig<T>` during dao initialization, the table config takes precedence and all JPA annotations are ignored.  So the answer to my own question is YES, it will override JPA annotation.